# Query against local MongoDB shard data only

Tags: mongodb

I have a sharded collection, with a shard key "user id". I would like to perform a query where, instead of passing the shard key, I simply restrict the query to only the data on the local mongos shard.

Is this possible / advisable?

Furthermore, can it be used with findAndModify? This would allow me to perform atomic updates on local documents, without specifying a shard key in the query.

***Edit***
As stated in some answers and comments below, my understanding of mongos vs. mongod was a little skewed. I now appreciate that mongos doesn't hold the local data.

Comment: I don't think this is possible yet, mongodb only either knows a query with or without shard key, not how to let the user dictate what shard a query should go

Comment: You want to perform a query on the local shard's data only? I think that's possible. But please clarify if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: The `mongos` routes queries to your shards and does not store any data itself .. so there is no such thing as "local" documents for a `mongos`. For a sharded collection you can only use `findAndModify()` with a query [based on the shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#sharded-collections); the shard key provides a guarantee that the requested document only exists on one shard.

Comment: @displayName: for a sharded collection, updates *have* to go through `mongos`. Bypassing `mongos` for sharded writes will definitely lead to problems such as data loss and unbalance .. so while it's *technically* possible to do so (i.e. not impossible), you should never recommend this. Similarly, reads for a sharded collection that bypass the `mongos` can find an inconsistent view of data. If the collection is sharded, you want to be using `mongos` to get supported outcomes.

Comment: @Stennie I think he meant to route through a mongos to a specific shard, not about circumventing the mongos altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Does `mongos` have any "local" data?

No. Each `mongos` daemon [routes queries to your shards](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/distributed-queries/) and does not store any data itself, so there is no such concept as "local" documents stored by a `mongos`. The `mongos` interface provides a logical view of the entire sharded cluster and does not have affinity to a specific shard.

Based on the type of query/command you send to `mongos`, the query will be:

- *Directed*: sent to a specific shard if the query uses the shard key
- *Targeted*: sent to applicable shards if the query includes multiple shard key values (or uses a prefix subset of a compound shard key)
- *Scatter/gather*: sent to all shards, if the query is not using the shard key

#### Should I read from shards directly?

No. It's technically *possible* to read data from the shards directly but definitely not recommendable as you can get an inconsistent view of data. For example, if there is a migration in progress the data will temporarily exist on both the donor shard and the target shard. Similarly, copies of documents may be [orphaned](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-orphaned-document) as the result of failed migrations.

A query through `mongos` correctly directs queries to the appropriate shard(s) and filters results based on the [sharded cluster metadata](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-metadata/).

#### Can I use `findAndModify()` on a sharded collection without a query based on a shard key?

No. For a sharded collection, `findAndModify()` [requires a query based on the shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#sharded-collections). The shard key provides a guarantee that the requested document only exists on one shard.

#### Can I update sharded collections without going through `mongos`?

No. All updates to a sharded collection must go through `mongos`.

Comment: Your answer has improved my understanding of how sharding works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind, that doing so is unadvised as traffic to a shared cluster should go through a mongos service.

That being said, It's possible to query the shard itself if you're performing the query locally on the shard instance.

I've never tried to do that programatically, but It may worth a shot.
You can either login directly to the machine running the shard, and open a mongo shell there (if you've never created a local user/password on it, I believe you can connect without credentials, otherwise, the mongod process on that specific shard must have it's own user/pass (as those which were created via the mongos are not recognised in the mongod shards.

As each shard knows its own data files only, and for example you'll run a count() operation on one of your collection you'll see that the result is only a portion of the actual collection size.

Comment: As noted in my earlier comment on the question; *possible* should definitely not be considered recommendable. For example, with `count()` you'll find that the sum of the counts via the shards (`mongod`) can easily be greater than the actual count of documents in the sharded collection (via `mongos`). For the latter part of the question it is definitely not possible to use `findAndModify()` on a sharded collection without including the shard key in the query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suspect I won't try this, but it's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague since you mix your English:

> I simply restrict the query to only the data on the local mongos shard.

The shard will infact be a `mongod` process, not a `mongos` process, however your English can make sense if you have a `mongos` per shard in which case it makes sense that you want to direct to a `mongos` on that shard that can query its local `mongod` data.

If you are considering on circumventing the `mongos` then @Stennies comment answers your question however, if your English means something else then I do not believe the `mongos` has a command switch to allow you to direct queries without a shard key currently.

Comment: If a query doesn't include the shard key, it's necessarily a scatter/gather query to all shards. This is the essence of sharding: the [shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/) determines the distribution of documents amongst the shards, and the `mongos` is the routing process.

Comment: @Stennie indeed, so there is no way to turn around and say to a mongos "I know the data is over here so only run over here" without using a shard key right?

Comment: @sammeaye: Correct .. the way to do that is to provide the shard key :). For a query other than the shard key, matching data could exist on any shard (and sometimes transiently on more than one shard, as in the case of active migrations). The shard key provides data locality because it matches how the data is partitioned, and the `mongos` references the sharded cluster metadata as a source of truth for which shards currently own chunk ranges for sharded collections.